# Who know the history of unix fork?

Tags: unix, history, fork

Fork is a great tool in unix.We can use it to generate our copy and change its behaviour.But I don't know the history of fork.

Does someone can tell me the story?

Comment: [A Story on Fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork())

Comment: Alpine's link is very good. If you want the full story, see http://www.amazon.com/Design-Operating-System-Prentice-Hall-Software/dp/0132017997/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1301206203&sr=1-1 Design of the unix Operating System by Maurice Bach. Failing these two, what did you find by googling? Please share your links.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, unlike many of the basic UNIX features, `fork` was a relative latecomer <sup>(a)</sup>.

The earliest existence of multiple processes within UNIX consisted of a few (fixed number of) processes, one per terminal that was attached to the PDP-7 machine <sup>(b)</sup>.

The basic idea was that the shell process for a given terminal would accept a command from the user, locate the program file, load a small bootstrap program into high memory and jump to it, passing enough details for the bootstrap code to load the program file.

The bootstrap code, after loading the program into low memory (overwriting the shell), would then jump to it.

When the program was finished, it would call `exit` but it wasn't like the `exit` we know and love today. *This* `exit` would simply reload the shell and run it using pretty much the same method used to load the program in the first place.

So it was really more like a rudimentary `exec` command, the one that replaces your current program with another, in the same process space.

The shell would `exec` your program then, when your program was done, it would again `exec` the shell by calling `exit`.

This method was similar to that found in many other interactive systems at the time, including the Multics from whence UNIX got its name.

From the two-way `exec`, it was actually not that big a leap to adding `fork` as a process duplicator to work in conjunction. While many systems run another program directly, it's this "just add what's needed" method which is responsible for the separation of duties between `fork` and `exec` in UNIX. It also resulted in a very simple `fork` function.

If you're interested in the early history of various features<sup>(c)</sup> of Unix, you *cannot* go past the article `The Evolution of the Unix Time-Sharing System` by Dennis Ritchie, presented at a 1979 conference in Australia, and subsequently published by AT&T.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Though I mean latecomer in the sense that the separation of the four fundamental forces in the universe was "late", happening some 0.00000000001 seconds after the big bang.</humour>.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> Since a question was raised in a comment as to how the shells were originally started off, there's a *great* resource holding very early source code for Unix over at [The Unix Heritage Society](http://tuhs.org), specifically [the source code archives](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl) and, in particular, the [first edition](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1).

The `init.s` file from the first edition shows how the fixed number of shell processes were created (slightly reformatted):

```
    ...
    mov    $itab, r1        / address of table to r1
1:
    mov    (r1)+, r0        / 'x, x=0, 1... to r0
    beq    1f               / branch if table end
    movb   r0, ttyx+8       / put symbol in ttyx
    jsr    pc, dfork        / go to make new init for this ttyx
    mov    r0, (r1)+        / save child id in word offer '0, '1, etc
    br     1b               / set up next child
1:
    ...

itab:
    '0; ..
    '1; ..
    '2; ..
    '3; ..
    '4; ..
    '5; ..
    '6; ..
    '7; ..
    0
```

Here you can see the snippet which creates the processes for each connected terminal. These are the days of hard-coded values, no auto detection of terminal quantity involved. The zero-terminated table at `itab` is used to create a number of processes and hopefully the comments from the code explain how (the only possibly tricky bit is the labels - though there are multiple `1` labels, you branch to the nearest one in a given direction, hence `1b` means the closest `1` label in the backwards direction).

The code shown simply processes the table, calling `dfork` to create a process for each terminal and start `getty`, the login prompt. The `getty` program, in turn, eventually started the shell. From that point, it's as I described in the main part of this answer.

---

<sup>(c)</sup> No paths (and use of temporary links to get around this limitation), limited processes, why there's a GECOS field in the password file, and all sorts of other trivia, generally interesting only to uber-geeks, of course.

Comment: So it sounds like the concept of loading another program's image into an existing process for the purposes of creating a child task predates the invention of fork, but how did the OS create each shell process in the first place? Surely the kernel must have some way to create a new process from a static executable image *ex nihilio*, and if so, why wasn't that functionality exposed in userland?

Comment: @Dai, see my update, specifically footnote `(a)`. The reason it wasn't exposed is probably because it wasn't necessary. Early UNIX had no pipes or background processes, it simply ran one process per terminal and there was a one-to-one mapping. In other words, a user would never create a new process, they would simply use the one already in existence to load a new program.

Comment: Nice answer, but "humour" at the top is not germane to the question at all.

Comment: Well, I would contend that it *is* relevant especially given that, without it, the "latecomer" comment is incorrect. However, I've moved it out of the main body so as not to distract from the meat of the answer.